# UIBarButton differences between View and tableViewControllers?

Tags: ios4, uiviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have a tab bar iPhone application.

Tab bar #1 has a table view controller. It pushes a detail screen onto the stack.
On the top right hand corner there is a UIBarButton that calls and action sheet. This
is all built programmatically through code and all works fine.

Tab bar #2 calls a table view controller than then loads a map view. The map view annotation callouts then open up a detail screen. On this screen, I'd like a UIBarButton. So far, I cannot get this to work. The button does not show up.

Any ideas why?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

UIBarButtonItem is not inherited from UIView.so u can't.

why dont u just use UIButton with Custom picture .

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html